# jquery .validate is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

`jQuery("form button[type=submit]:first").closest("form").validate` is not a function

Everything used to work in firefox 3.6.17, but now in ff 4.0.1 this is broken. This works in Chrome. I've verified that this is a Mac OSX ff 4.0.1 issue because I tried on an ubuntu machine running ff 4.0.1.

this is my code:

```
jQuery("form button[type=submit]:first").closest("form").validate({
  ignore: ":hidden",
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    if(!jQuery("#phone_1 input").hasClass("error")){
      jQuery("form button[type=submit]").hide();
      stripPhone();
      return false;
    }
  },
  rules: {
    "lead[first_name]": {
      required: true, minlength: 2
    },
    "lead[last_name]": {
      required: true, minlength: 2
    },
    "lead[phone_1]": {
      required: true, phone_state_validation: true
    },
    "lead[email_address]": {
      required: true,email: true
    },
    "lead[state]": {
      required: true
    },
    "lead[zip_code]": {
      required: true, rangelength: [5, 5], digits: true
    },
    "lead[education_level_reached]": {
      required: false
    }
  },
  messages: {
    "lead[first_name]":"Please enter a valid name",
    "lead[last_name]":"Please enter a valid name",
    "lead[phone_1]":"Please enter a phone number with 10 digits",
    "lead[email_address]":"Please enter a valid email",
    "lead[state]":"Please choose one",
    "lead[zip_code]":"Please enter a 5 digit zip",
    "lead[education_level_reached]":"Please choose one"
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show us what version of jquery and jquery validate your using ? by the way your selector seems wacky to me i would give the form an id and target it that way

Comment: I am using jquery 1.4.2 and validation plug-in 1.7. I can't add an id because its a dynamic form and changes alot. I changed the versions to jquery 1.6.0 and validation plug-in 1.8 and still same problem.

Comment: is see your using jquery instead of $ are you loading other libraries if so are you using noconfict ?

Comment: i would also try kicking jquery down to 1.5.2  and see if that helps things

Comment: @Chris, does the problem still occur if you run Firefox in safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the validation plugin is loaded in the page? Perhaps something in FF4 is preventing it from loading, since usually when you get 'is not a function' it means that the function you're trying to call has not been attached to the jQuery object.

Comment: please be sure to complete your answers before you post

Comment: yes i verified that the validation plugin being loaded. Atleast looking at the net tab tells me it is loaded with a 200 ok.

Comment: In Firebug's console if you go: **$.fn.validate** -- does it say undefined?

Comment: $.fn.validate - yes its undefined

Comment: Then something in FF4 is preventing the plugin from properly loading or initializing. I bet in Chrome's console you'll find that $.fn.validate is not undefined